# MYSQL Distinct and Show Group Values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

Is this possible in mysql query..

I want to select distinct client name, group by client name..

then show the values in the group_name..

```
table 1

id    client_name   Group_id     
------------------------------
1     IBM               1
2     DELL              1   
3     DELL              2
4     MICROSOFT         3 

table 2

id    group_name
------------------
1     Group1      
2     Group2     
3     Group3
```

I need a result like this

```
client_name      merge_group   
-------------------------
IBM                Group1
DELL               Group1, Group2
MICROSOFT          Group3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT Client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(group_name) merge_group
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.Client_name
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Result:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ CLIENT_NAME ║  MERGE_GROUP  ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ IBM         ║ Group1        ║
║ DELL        ║ Group1,Group2 ║
║ MICROSOFT   ║ Group3        ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63b32/6)

Comment: @MarkieMark - Yes that's correct. Also consider your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2110737/markie-mark?tab=questions) if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ::

```
Select tab1.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(tab2.group_name SEPARATOR ',') as groupedColumn

from table1 tab1 
inner join table2 tab2 ON tab1.group_id = tab2.id
GROUP BY tab1.Client_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.group_name) merge_group 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.client_name;
```